# Saving url-loaded pdf string to valid file

Tags: python, pdf, save, binaryfiles

Lets say I have

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://url.to/file.do?page=1")
```

and after some checks with `html = response.read()` I assure `response` is a PDF file and not error or warning html that can happend often with the page i'm dealing

How can I then just save the PDF as a valid .pdf file?
I tried opening a file cursor, writting `html` there and saving but it won't generate a valid readable PDF.

Any straight forward clue? Do I really have to use PyPDF or something?

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

Write `html` instead of `response`. `response` does not actually contain the data.

#### Explanation

`response` is similar to a file object created with `open`. As such, it stores things such as the open socket and takes care of making the proper request, but doesn't actually contain the data (at least in an easily accessible fashion). Rather, you read the data from it using `read` and then use it.

```
>>> response = urllib.urlopen(url)
>>> html = response.read()
>>> response
<addinfourl at 1234567890 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x9876543210>>
>>> html
(whatever data is downloaded)
```

Comment: edited the question. Its `html` instead of `response`. but even this way Adobe Reader can't read the file and say its invalid..